# GPU trained .pb model doesn't work on CPU only machine

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, gpu, protocol-buffers

I retraind TensorFlow Inception-v3 model file 'retrained_graph.pb' by using GPU.

And I transferred 'retrained_graph.pb' file to AWS EC2 t2.micro server(ubuntu 16.04.2), which has no GPU.

when I tried below inference script 'label_image.py' on my EC2 server,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile


# change this as you see fit
image_path = sys.argv[1]

# Read in the image_data
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                   in tf.gfile.GFile('/home/ubuntu/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt')]

# Unpersists graph from file

with tf.gfile.FastGFile('./retrained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
    softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        print('%s::%.5f::' % (human_string, score))
```

It doesn't work with this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label_image.py", line 20, in <module>
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

But inference on the other model which is trained non-gpu support works well on same script 'label_image.py'

How can I run this inference script with non-GPU environment?

Comment: Can you verify if you have the same version of TensorFlow on both the machines?

Comment: I have same error. Did you can solve it?